# svn merging of a subtree, then the full tree

Tags: svn, merge, subtree, mergeinfo

In my company we use SVN to merge subtrees of the trunk into the branches and vice versa.

For example, we merge /Trunk/folderA/ --> /Branch/folderA/ and not always perform the root merge from /Trunk/ --> /Branch/.

I noticed that the mergeinfo of each folder keeps track of the folder's older merges, and we expect svn to "elide" changes that were already applied in past merges of subtrees. This feature is specifically described in the SVN book in a chapter called "Subtree Merges and Subtree Mergeinfo"
Link:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync.subtree

The problem:
When we now perform a root merge, svn ignores the subtree mergeinfo and tries to merge old changes back into the subtree. In other words, it does not "elide" previous merges as described in the book.

Does anyone know why it happens, and are there solutions?

Thanks

Comment: " When we now perform a root merge, svn ignores the subtree mergeinfo and tries to merge old changes back into the subtree." - show samples, *not "impressions"*!

Comment: @LazyBadger
Branch folder's mergeinfo towards Trunk is /Trunk:126977-136080.
Branch subfolder's mergeinfo towards Trunk is /Trunk/RTL/phy/ldu:126977-137701.

When merging Trunk-->Branch I get:
C    RTL/phy/ldu/file1.txt
   C RTL/phy/ldu/file2.sv
C    RTL/phy/ldu/file3.v
--- Merging r137702 through r144554 into 'RTL/phy/ldu':
U    RTL/phy/ldu/file4.v
U    RTL/phy/ldu/file5.v
U    RTL/phy/ldu/file6.v
 G   RTL/phy/ldu

When merging Trunk subfolder to Branch subfolder I get:
--- Merging r137702 through r144554 into '.':
U    file4.v
U    file5.v
U    file6.v
 G   .
No conflicts. Only real updates.

Comment: @LazyBadger I hope the above "samples" are sufficient. If not, please describe what is missing. What would you like to know about the process? I actually want to encourage answers without supporting "samples", because I would like to know, in general, whether SVN supports merging sub-trees while keeping the tree healthy. The SVN book says YES (although they "don't recommend" it). We see it cannot. Do you know about bugs and solutions in our method of merging? Thanks in advance!

Comment: without diffs I suppose U in files in subtree only means "Removing old mergeinfo" (as written in doc) - and still **don't see real error** Merge-Changes-In-Content-Again